# Notepad++ XML Tools Autospacing Logic

Tags: html, xml, plugins, notepad++, auto-indent

PLEASE HELP ME

So I started using the CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+B autospacing feature that comes with the XML Tools plugin using Notepad++ v7.2.  Everything is working fine I just have a question about the logic the plugin uses.  In this excerpt of code:

```
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img id="codeImg" alt="matrix code" src="http://i860.photobucket.com/albums/ab170/gondrongsolo/background.gif">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <em>Python</em> programming</li>
                                    <li>Shell scripting</li>
                                    <li>Reddit addict</li>
                                    <li>Fitness nut</li>
                                    <li>Raidboss Gamer</li>
                                </ul>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Why does using the autospacing feature correct it like this?  Shouldn't the first `<tr>` match the same spacing with the `</tr>` closing tag?  I'm finding this happens everything I inserted a tag that doesn't need a closing tag, such as `img` or `p` tags.

I would really like to be able to **fix the auto formatting** because it allows me to read my code more clearly and would greatly appreciate a response.  If I need a different plugin please direct me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So despite the fact you do not ***need*** to make `img` a self closing tag in order to use it in html, you ***can*** use it at the end of the tag.  If using this plugin you can make it happy when you do `<img ... />` without causing errors on the web page.  The plugin will read this correctly then and fix the issue resulting in the following formatting:

```
                     <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img id="codeImg" alt="matrix code" src="http://i860.photobucket.com/albums/ab170/gondrongsolo/background.gif"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <em>Python</em> programming</li>
                                <li>Shell scripting</li>
                                <li>Reddit addict</li>
                                <li>Fitness nut</li>
                                <li>Raidboss Gamer</li>
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```